Two chart smooth structure on $\mathbb{R}$ is diffeomorphic to $(\mathbb{R},\operatorname{id})$.
It's known that $\mathbb{R}$ only has one smooth structure up to diffeomorphism. I'm asked to show that any smooth structure on $\mathbb{R}$ equivalent to an atlas with two charts is
diffeomorphic to the smooth structure determined by ($\mathbb{R}$, id). It is easy to prove any one chart atlas $\{(\mathbb{R}, \psi)\}$ is diffeomorphic to the canonical one, as $\psi$ is a diffeomorphism onto $(\psi(\mathbb{R}),$ id), which is a connected open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and there exists standard diffeomorphisms from $\psi(\mathbb{R})$ to $(\mathbb{R}, \mathrm{id})$. My hope is to show that any two-chart atlas on $\mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to some one chart atlas $\{(\mathbb{R}, \psi)\}$ and the statement follows. However, I do not know how to construct this.

Think about how the two given charts can overlap and try to define your $\psi$ by smoothly switching from one of the given maps to to the other. You might need to flip one of the maps.

Thank you! I can certainly use a bump function supported in the overlap to construct $\psi$ so that it agrees with the chart maps at non-overlapping regions and transitions smoothly in between. However, $\psi$ is not necessarily a homeomorphism onto its image… Is there a way to resolve this?

There's a sign issue you can resolve by first composing the given maps with negation if needed so that both are increasing functions. I had overlooked the other issue (where the interpolated map is still not increasing on the overlap region), but I'm thinking you can resolve this by adding a constant to one of the given maps.
